# "To be so", is it a real phrase? If so, what is the correct way to use it?

Tags: grammar

Can I say: To be so, you must do so & so..

For example: Do you want to be wealthy? To be so, you should ...

Or is "to become so" more correct? or neither?

Comment: I think this should be migrated to the stack exchange "English Language & Usage"

Comment: Questions about whether a certain phrase is correct, or how to use it, belong on English.SE. This is the second time you've asked a question here that belonged there. Please keep that in mind.